# Парсинг  номера телефона

Tags: парсер

http://novosibirsk.drom.ru/bentley/continental_gt/11750930.html
с этой странички, после нажатия на кнопку приходит xml в котором хранится номер телефона, но он отличается от оригинала на 3 первых символа. Как достать правильный номер?

Comment: Какую кнопку? Кому приходит XML? Объясните проблему.

Comment: кнопку показать телефон. Xml приходит после get запроса,после нажатия на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

<response><error><![CDATA[0]]></error>
<contacts><![CDATA[+7 (913) 910-5827]]></contacts>
<obj_id><![CDATA[show_contacts]]></obj_id>
</response>

Вообще-то возвращает без изменений. может у тебя ошибка в коде запроса?